# Regular Expression to match 3 letter strings

Tags: regex

Looking for regular expression in VBScript to match 3 letter strings to match words like JAN, jan, FEB, feb etc.
How to specify this constrain?

Comment: Why not specify all 12 months in regex?

Comment: No way to find 3 alphabets?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and let us know [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to match just three alphabets just use

```
[a-z]{3}|[A-Z]{3}
```

I have assumed that you need all letter capital or all letter small.